# Как получить родительский элемент с определенным CSS-свойством?

Tags: jquery

Определяю родительский элемент так:

```
var parent = $(".element").parent();
```

Но мне нужно в parent записать родителя, который имеет свойство "position: relative".

Например, есть такая HTML-структура:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Например, если блок .`inner` имеет свойство `"position: relative"`, то в parent записываем `.inner`.
Но если `.inner` не имеет такого свойства, то нужно подняться выше и проверить свойство для `.wrapper`, и записать в parent `.wrapper`, если оно имеет свойство `"position: relative"`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
var parent = $(".element").parent();
var pos = $(parent).css('position'); // Получаем position
if (pos != 'relative') { // Если position inner не relative;
    parent = $(parent).parent(); // Получаем родителя inner
    pos = $(parent).css('position'); // Получаем position
    if (pos != 'relative') parent = undefined; // Если position wrapper не relative;
}
console.log(parent);
```